# Tailwind Elements: Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') when using Carousel

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am reviewing the error: `Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')` when using the [Carousel component](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/). In my case I am mapping through an array of images and adding carousel-items to the carousel like so:

```
<div className="carousel-inner relative w-full overflow-hidden max-h-[300px]">
  {project.imageslist.map((image, i) => (
    <div
      key={i}
      className={`carousel-item ${i < 1 ? "active" : ""} float-left w-full`}>
      <img
        src={image.listitemimg}
        className="block w-full"
        alt="Wild Landscape"
      />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Any ideas?

I've tried manually adding each `carousel-item` instead of using map to map through an array, but I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question was that it's required to also add the same number of `button` elements as number of slides you have. For example, I added 4 slides (`carousel-item`)'s but only had 3 buttons within the `carousel-indicator`. So I added an extra button with the correct details (`data-bs-slide` and `aria-label` incremented by 1).

Example (fix):

```
<div
  className="carousel-indicators absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center p-0 mb-4">
  <button
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCrossfade"
    data-bs-slide-to="0"
    className="active"
    aria-current="true"
    aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
  <button
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCrossfade"
    data-bs-slide-to="1"
    aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
  <button
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCrossfade"
    data-bs-slide-to="2"
    aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  <!-- Fix added below -->
  <button
    type="button"
    data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCrossfade"
    data-bs-slide-to="3"
    aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be an issue with the **project.imageslist** array being null or undefined.

Try checking first with **project.imageslist.length > 0** before mapping through the array:

```
{project.imageslist.length > 0 && project.imageslist.map((image, i) => (
    <div
      key={i}
      className={`carousel-item ${i < 1 ? "active" : ""} float-left w-full`}>
      <img
        src={image.listitemimg}
        className="block w-full"
        alt="Wild Landscape"
      />
    </div>
  ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out and posted the answer :)!